# Why SFSpeechRecognizer doesn't working in ipad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, sfspeechrecognizer

SFSpeechRecognizer is working well in IOS
But it doesn't available in IPAD.
I don't know how to fix it.
Please give me a solution.

```
func recordAndRecognizeSpeech() {
        
        let node = audioEngine.inputNode
        let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 0, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
            self.request.append(buffer)
        }
        audioEngine.prepare()
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            return print(error)
        }
        guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
            // A recognizer is not supported for the current locale
            return
        }
        if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
            print("Speech recognition not available")
            return
        }
        isFinal = false

        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler:  { result, error in
            if let result = result {
                self.recognizedSpeechTextView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                self.qnaTextField.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                self.textFieldDidChange(self.qnaTextField)

            } else if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            
            if !self.isFinal {
                self.startSpeechTimer()
            }
        })
    }
```

in iPad call
function if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
print("Speech recognition not available")
return
}

Answer (score 0):

At least two possible reasons SFSpeechRecognizer.isAvailable might return false exist:

- Hey Siri is not enabled on the device. Toggle on Settings -> Siri & Search -> Listen for “Hey Siri” (iOS 15)
- According to the documentation: [for some languages, the recognizer might require an Internet connection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer)